# Is there any way to have a batch file send information to an open telnet connection?

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to make a native IRC client for windows in batch. You can connect to IRC servers over telnet, but you have to type in your user and nick quite fast or the server will drop the connection

```
SET /P server=[Server Address: ]
telnet %server% 6667

SET /P user=[Username/nick:]
echo "USER %user% 8 * : %user%"
echo "NICK %user%"
```

The program will connect to the specified server, but I am unable to echo the user and nick commands to the server.

Comment: You can use Albert Yale's [Telnet Scripting Tool](http://support.moonpoint.com/downloads/windows/network/Telnet/tst10.php)

Answer (score 0):

The windows built-in telnet client is not scriptabe.

try this (it is a selfcompiled bat/c# script and should be saved with `.bat` extension . It is taken from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library)):

```
// 2>nul||@goto :batch
/*
:batch
@echo off
setlocal

::delete line when ready
del %~n0.exe >nul 2>nul


:: find csc.exe
set "csc="
for /r "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\" %%# in ("*csc.exe") do  set "csc=%%#"

if not exist "%csc%" (
   echo no .net framework installed
   exit /b 10
)

if not exist "%~n0.exe" (
   call %csc% /nologo /warn:0 /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0" || (
      exit /b %errorlevel% 
   )
)
%~n0.exe %*
endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%

*/

// minimalistic telnet implementation
// conceived by Tom Janssens on 2007/06/06  for codeproject
//
// http://www.corebvba.be



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace MinimalisticTelnet
{
    enum Verbs {
        WILL = 251,
        WONT = 252,
        DO = 253,
        DONT = 254,
        IAC = 255
    }

    enum Options
    {
        SGA = 3
    }

    class TelnetConnection
    {
        TcpClient tcpSocket;

        int TimeOutMs = 100;

        public TelnetConnection(string Hostname, int Port)
        {
            tcpSocket = new TcpClient(Hostname, Port);

        }

        public string Login(string Username,string Password,int LoginTimeOutMs)
        {
            int oldTimeOutMs = TimeOutMs;
            TimeOutMs = LoginTimeOutMs;
            string s = Read();
            if (!s.TrimEnd().EndsWith(":"))
               throw new Exception("Failed to connect : no login prompt");
            WriteLine(Username);

            s += Read();
            if (!s.TrimEnd().EndsWith(":"))
                throw new Exception("Failed to connect : no password prompt");
            WriteLine(Password);

            s += Read();
            TimeOutMs = oldTimeOutMs;
            return s;
        }

        public void WriteLine(string cmd)
        {
            Write(cmd + "\n");
        }

        public void Write(string cmd)
        {
            if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return;
            byte[] buf = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd.Replace("\0xFF","\0xFF\0xFF"));
            tcpSocket.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }

        public string Read()
        {
            if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return null;
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            do
            {
                ParseTelnet(sb);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
            } while (tcpSocket.Available > 0);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public bool IsConnected
        {
            get { return tcpSocket.Connected; }
        }

        void ParseTelnet(StringBuilder sb)
        {
            while (tcpSocket.Available > 0)
            {
                int input = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                switch (input)
                {
                    case -1 :
                        break;
                    case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                        // interpret as command
                        int inputverb = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                        if (inputverb == -1) break;
                        switch (inputverb)
                        {
                            case (int)Verbs.IAC: 
                                //literal IAC = 255 escaped, so append char 255 to string
                                sb.Append(inputverb);
                                break;
                            case (int)Verbs.DO: 
                            case (int)Verbs.DONT:
                            case (int)Verbs.WILL:
                            case (int)Verbs.WONT:
                                // reply to all commands with "WONT", unless it is SGA (suppres go ahead)
                                int inputoption = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                                if (inputoption == -1) break;
                                tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)Verbs.IAC);
                                if (inputoption == (int)Options.SGA )
                                    tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WILL:(byte)Verbs.DO); 
                                else
                                    tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WONT : (byte)Verbs.DONT); 
                                tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)inputoption);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        sb.Append( (char)input );
                        break;
                }
            }
        }


        ////
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string server=args[0];
            int port= Int32.Parse(args[1]);

            string user=args[2];
            string password=args[3];

            string command=args[4];
            //create a new telnet connection to hostname "gobelijn" on port "23"
            TelnetConnection tc = new TelnetConnection(server, port);


            //login with user "root",password "rootpassword", using a timeout of 100ms, and show server output
            string s="";
            string prompt = "";
            try{
                s = tc.Login(user, password,100);
                Console.Write(s);

                // server output should end with "$" or ">", otherwise the connection failed
                prompt = s.TrimEnd();
                prompt = s.Substring(prompt.Length -1,1);
                if (prompt != "$" && prompt != ">" )
                    throw new Exception("Connection failed");
            }catch(Exception e){

            }





            // while connected
            while (tc.IsConnected && prompt.Trim() != "exit" )
            {
                // display server output
                Console.Write(tc.Read());

                // send client input to server
                //prompt = Console.ReadLine();
                try{
                    tc.WriteLine(command);

                    // display server output
                    Console.Write(tc.Read());
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("***DISCONNECTED");
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }

        ////
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
telnetcs.bat localhost 21 admin password command
```

Testing was pretty limited , script is not fail safe ,but if you are able to send a command it can be improved.